# Unable to run debugger for jruby

Tags: debugging, jruby

I've tried to follow various online references for jruby debugger but it is not working.

I've tried following: first change to root (does not work as normal user) then:

```
jruby -S gem install ruby-debug-base


jruby -S gem install ruby-debug-base
```

But then the following command fails:

```
jruby --debug -S rdebug ./classifier-wf.rb 

Gem::LoadError: Could not find columnize (>= 0.1) amongst [jdbc-mysql-5.1.24, rake-10.0.3, ruby-debug-0.10.4, ruby-debug-base-0.10.4-java]
           to_specs at /opt/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency.rb:247
activate_dependencies at /opt/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/specification.rb:777
               each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
activate_dependencies at /opt/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/specification.rb:766
           activate at /opt/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/specification.rb:750
                gem at /opt/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems.rb:1232
             (root) at /opt/jruby-1.7.3/bin/rdebug:22
```

I am running jruby 1.7.3.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) instead of other debugger gems, soon you'll be addicted to it.

Comment: pry-debugger doesn't work for jruby https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger/issues/26

Comment: There is no need for pry-debugger, just add `binding.pry` to wherever you need a break.